# Локализация Java-класса в Android

Tags: java, android, locale

Знаю как локализовать ресурсы приложения (папку res).

Но у меня есть java-класс. В нем 3 больших строковых массива.

Как локализовать именно класс в приложении? (кроме очевидного но очень неудобного, переписать каждый элемент класса в string.xml)

Comment: А в чем неудобство создания `<string-array>` в _strings.xml_?

Comment: @Regent в том, что эти массивы связаны друг с другом. ( mass1[0] mass2[0] mass3[0] ) и ( mass1[1] mass2[1] mass3[1] ) и тд и тп

Comment: @Wlad, а можете показать пример тех массивов и как связь между ними поменяет использовать strings.xml?

Comment: @Wlad, Вы можете использовать их точно так же - единственное отличие, что вместо инициализации в коде Вы будете получать их из ресурсов

Comment: @gil9red это никак не помешает и ничего не поменяет. я знаю этот вариант, но лично для меня он неудобный.

Comment: @woesss да, я это знаю. можно ли как локализовать сам класс? вопрос в этом заключается. если нет - придется делать через <string-array>

Comment: @Wlad можно хранить все массивы в одном классе и выбирать нужный в зависимости от `Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();` или чего-то другого. Можно ли создать несколько классов, в каждом из которых будет по одной версии массива? В принципе, можно (но пары "путь+название" классов всё равно должны быть уникальными) - определять язык (`Locale` и т.д.), после чего, например с помощью рефлексии, получать нужный массив. Вот только для статичных данных всё это звучит сложнее, чем _strings.xml_

Comment: @Regent согласен. лучше уже в строки все перенести. спасибо)

Comment: К тому же новые локали потом добавлять будет проще через ресурсы, а так же отдавать их на локализацию переводчику. Если всё же интересны для расширения кругозора другие варианты - поищите статейки о том как это делается в чистой java

Comment: @woesss нет, я искал (хоть и понимал что это не логично) способ локализации кода как ресурсов самого андроида.